# SQLite - no such column: X

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know that problem lies in **SELECT** being executed last. When **CASE** is executed, column X does not exist yet. Columns X and its values appear from subtraction of columns a and b values => **ROUND**((a-b)),2) **AS** [X] You can notice it in the full code lower:
**Basically the question is the following:** how do I make column X appear with its values before **CASE**.

```
SELECT 
    e, a, b,ROUND((a-b)),2) AS [X],
    CASE WHEN X BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 'Good Choice'
    ELSE 'bad choice' END AS 'choice'
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.column_1 = table_2.column_2
Where BBB = "VVV" OR BBB = "CCC"
GROUP BY column_1;
```

Comment: What is the current error message?

Comment: SQLite supports CTEs (`WITH` clauses): https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html. You can use one here to produce a rowset with columns `a, e, b, X` and then have the outer (final) query refer to `X`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such column: X

Comment: @j_random_hacker thank you for that hint, but can you please write that in the form for of code? Its only my second day with SQL, I looked into the link you provided, but I can't make anything out of documentation files)

Comment: I don't want to do the exercise for you, but you need a non-`RECURSIVE` CTE here, and I admit there doesn't seem to be a good example of that on the page. Here's an example that you can hopefully generalise: `WITH helper AS (SELECT x, y, x + y AS z FROM table42) SELECT x, y, z FROM helper WHERE z > 50;`

Comment: @ j_random_hacker tbh i am even more confused now)) and don't worry for doing exercise for me, I with this query already went far beyond from the stuff I was asked to do in the first place. Again, thank you so much for replies, but i am not sure where to put that in my code, I assume after all that  -  WITH helper AS (SELECT x, y, x + y AS z FROM table42) SELECT x, y, z FROM helper WHERE z > 50;  - comes the CASE, but im still not sure. Let me see maybe I can make sense of it

Comment: No, the `CASE` doesn't come after that. Replace part of the second `SELECT` with the `CASE`. Also I'm not familiar with SQLite syntax, but I strongly doubt you want single quotes around `X` in `CASE WHEN 'X'` -- that would specify the literal string "X". Just write plain `X`.

Comment: My example was only intended to show you how the `WITH` clause builds a rowset whose columns you can name, and can access via those names in the subsequent main/final/outer `SELECT` query.

Comment: yes, I fixed quotes around X a while ago, sorry, forgot to modify it here

Comment: @j_random_hacker thank you for the replies, I will try to solve it with your solution too, but in the morning) right now my head isn't quite in shape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to the alias `X` inside the same select in which it was defined.  Just repeat the round expression in this case:

```sql
SELECT e, a, b, ROUND(a - b, 2) AS X,
       CASE WHEN ROUND(a - b, 2) BETWEEN 5 AND 10
            THEN 'Good Choice' ELSE 'bad choice' END AS choice
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2
WHERE BBB = 'VVV' OR BBB = 'CCC'
GROUP BY column1;
```

Comment: My god, I can believe I am that stupid, how could I miss that solution. Sir, thank you so much, I can finally go to bed now))

Comment: @StunedtStudencheskiy I would have used the word ignorant instead, but learning easily fixes that problem.  Happy to help you.